# Not Able To Identify Currently Running Class While Running .War File

Tags: java

I am having .War file which i am running, but i am not able to identify which class is currently running ?....   Can Any One Give Suggestion For This:- How to Identify Currently Running Class

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve. It is not clear what you mean by "running class". Why do you need to know? What's the goal?

Comment: I am having .war file and I deployed that .war file in Tomcat now when that   file is opened on any Browser,one front page is coming , for currently opened page I want know the related class ,How I will Know , and also i don't have any souce for that code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you can do the following:

Unpack the `.war` file. (It's actually a `ZIP` file) Then take a look at `WEB-INF/web.xml`. There you can find the servlet mapping. It defines which request url is mapped to which servlet (java class).

Answer (score 0):

> Use debug mode while starting server and press F5 to run it line by line.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html